# Automatic nested hash keys with ability to append value

Tags: ruby

I have an arbitrary list of file names I'd like to sort into a hash. I'd like to do it like this:

```
## Example file name 'hello.world.random_hex"

file_name_list.each do |file|
  name_array = file.split('.')
  files[name_array[0].to_sym][name_array[1].to_sym] << file
end
```

Those keys may not exist and I'd like for them to be automatically created with a default value of [] so the << works as expected. The final files hash would look like:

```
{ :hello => { :world => [ "hello.world.random_hex", "hello.world.other_random_hex" ] } }
```

How can I initialize files to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If there are always two levels of keys like this, you can do it using the block form of Hash.new:

```
files = Hash.new {|k,v| k[v] = Hash.new {|k,v| k[v] = [] }}
```

(On the other hand, if the keys can be nested to an arbitrary depth, this is much harder because the Hash can't know whether the value for a nonexistent key should be a Hash or an Array at the time it is accessed.)